# bash - parse argument list in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script called foo.sh that contains something like

```
exec myapp -o size=100m -f
```

Any idea how to create another script that parses foo.sh and retrieves the value of `size`?  One can assume myapp only appears once in foo.sh, but the order of `size` argument can appear anywhere in the argument list

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) in a shell :

```
$ grep -oP 'myapp.*?size=\K\d+m' foo.sh
100m
```

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) in a shell :

```
$ awk -F'size='  '{sub(/ -f/, "");print $2}' foo.sh
100m
```

or

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/.*size=([0-9]+m).*/, "\\1", $0)}' foo.sh
100m
```

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) in a shell :

```
$ perl -lne 'print $1 if /exec.*?size=(\d+m)/' foo.sh
100m
```

Or using a shell funny trick :

```
$ declare $(grep -oP "\b\w+=\w+\b" foo.sh)
$ echo $size
100m
```

Comment: What a nice set of options!

Answer (score 0):

```
cat foo.sh | egrep -o 'size=[[:digit:]]+' | awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

Comment: this almost works.  I was hoping to get everything between 'size=' and the next space character

Comment: `cat | grep | awk` is a useless use of cat & grep. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the sed approach. This one short-circuits once it's found the line. Useful if the file is very long and the target is likely near the beginning.

```
sed  -ne '/exec myapp -o size=/{s/[^0-9]*\([m0-9]*\).*/\1/;p;q;}'
```

Once it finds the correct line, it extracts the size value, prints it, and then quits.